# How to correctly solve this problem inside the loop?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of size (16,). How can I correctly add a sequence to it to get an array of size (16,3) inside the for loop. IMPORTANT POINT: the number of elements in array "values" can change.

```
import numpy as np

num_test = 16
pred = np.zeros(num_test, np.bool)

items = 3
values = np.repeat(True, 3)

print(values)

for i in range(num_test):

  # How to correctly solve this problem inside the loop?
  pred[i] = values

# For this particular case, the output should be an array of size (16,3)
print(pred)
```

Comment: first create array with size `(16,3)` and later you can replace values using `pred[i] = values`. You can't convert `(16,)` to `(16, 3)` by `pred[i] = values` - you would have to first create 3 arrays `(16,)` and laste `stack` them.

Comment: Good morning. Thank you very much for your prompt reply. Received additional information today:

It is necessary to find the most common boolean value in each line and write it exactly to the array (16,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't convert `(16,)` to `(16,3)` using `pred[i] = values`.

You have to create array `(16,3)` before you try to use `pred[i] = values`.

```
pred = np.zeros((num_test, items), np.bool)
```

---

```
import numpy as np

num_test = 16
items = 3

pred = np.zeros((num_test, items), np.bool)  # `(16, 3)`

values = np.repeat(True, items)

#pred[:] = values

for i in range(num_test):
  pred[i] = values

print(pred.shape)
print(pred)
```

---

Eventually you can first create 3 arrays `(16,)` and later `stack` them

```
import numpy as np

num_test = 16
items = 3

pred1 = np.zeros(num_test, np.bool)
pred2 = np.zeros(num_test, np.bool)
pred3 = np.zeros(num_test, np.bool)

values = np.repeat(True, items)

#pred1[:] = values[0]
#pred2[:] = values[1]
#pred3[:] = values[2]

for i in range(num_test):
    pred1[i] = values[0]
    pred2[i] = values[1]
    pred3[i] = values[2]

pred = np.stack([pred1, pred2, pred3], axis=1)

print(pred.shape)
print(pred)
```

but it would need to use `for`-loop to create list with `pred1, pred2`, etc.

---

OR maybe first create normal list and later convert it ot `np.array`

```
import numpy as np

num_test = 16
items = 3

values = np.repeat(True, items)

all_values = []

for _ in range(num_test):
    all_values.append(values)

#all_values = [values for _ in range(num_test)]

pred = np.array(all_values, np.bool)

print(pred.shape)
print(pred)
```

Comment: Good morning. Thank you very much for your prompt reply. Received additional information today:

It is necessary to find the most common boolean value in each line and write it exactly to the array (16,)

Comment: for standard list you could use `values.count(True)`, `values.count(False)` and compare results and use `if/else` to get `True` or `False`. For `numpy.array` you can convert to standard list `values.tolist().count(True)`, `values.tolist().count(False)`

Comment: maybe you could do it in one line (with `for`-loop) `pred[i] = (values[i].count(True) >= values[i].count(False))` - it there is more `True` then `count(True) >= count(False)` will give `True`, and if there is more `False` then the same `count(True) >= count(False)` will give `False`

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations, at the moment I am working on an option with:   ```print ('Current most frequent item:', bool (np.bincount (values2 [row]). argmax ()))``` Where ```values2``` - it is a nampi array of 16 lines each with two values (True or False).